# After a change in the editor, get the text and send it through socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, ace-editor

As described in the title I need to get the code after a change event in the editor, and send that code via a socket. I can send code via socket to the editor but I'm having trouble get the code.

```
if(socket !== undefined){
//put latest string in DB to ACE
 socket.on('output', function(data){
   if(data.length){
     var x = data.length-1;
     editor.setValue(data[x].code);
   }
 });

// after keydown put new string to DB
 editor.on('change', function(data){
   var code = editor.getValue();
     socket.emit('input',{
       code: code
     });
 });
}
<script src="src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
var editor = ace.edit("aceEditor");
var code = editor.getValue();

//editor.setValue("new code here");
editor.getSession().setValue(editor.getValue(), 1);
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

HTML:

```
<div id="aceEditor" style="height: 500px; width: 500px">some text</div>
```

I getting an error in the browser console saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: editor is not defined". Anyone know why this is wrong?

Comment: It appears to be a scoping issue, hard to tell you exactly what's going on (other than editor is not available in this scope) just from what you posted.

Comment: you need to wait for the editor to load before you can subscribe events onto it. since the first code block waits on the socket message, that probably gives `window.editor` time to boot up...

Comment: I'm not sure how to load the editor? is that setting up the editor